# Tcl regsub: replace a unescapped " with other character '}'

Tags: regex, tcl

I was trying to use `regsub` to replace all the unescapped `"` to `}`. I got the following.

```
% set st {hello "hi this athat afsd\" adsfasdf"}
% regsub -all {(?!\\)\"} $st \}
hello }hi this athat afsd\} adsfasdf}
```

What I wanted was
`hello }hi this athat afsd\" adsfasdf}`. Please let me know what went wrong.

Comment: try this regex `(?<!\\)\"` and then replace the matched chars with `}`

Comment: @AvinashRaj error: `couldn't compile regular expression pattern: quantifier operand invalid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the regex that you are using isn't really doing what you think it does. Literally, it tries to match `(?!\)"` (double quotes with a negative lookahead containing one backslash before it).

Let's try to see in detail how things are working. I'll take a sample just before and after the match, with added spaces to make it clearer.

```
a f s d \ " 
       ^
```

Here the engine looks ahead and sees a backslash. Because of the negative lookahead, the match fails and thus continues on with the string.

```
a f s d \ "
         ^
```

Now that it passed the backslash, it tries to make a match again. There are no backslashes ahead, so the negative lookahead doesn't stop the match. Next, the regex tries to match the double quotes which is successful.

Usually, you would need a *lookbehind* to do what you intended to do because a lookahead cannot check something that it has already passed, but a negative lookbehind does just that. Unfortunately, tcl does not support lookbehinds (and doesn't really need one since there are already more efficient workarounds) so it would be better to match the escaped quotes as well, but deal with them separately (here by placing them back exactly as they were).

For instance, you can use something like

```
 regsub -all {(\\")|"} $st {\1} result
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use back reference to achieve the same.

```
set st {hello "hi this athat afsd\" adsfasdf"}
puts $st
regsub -all {([^\\])"} $st \\1\} result
puts $result
```

**Output:**

```
hello "hi this athat afsd\" adsfasdf"
hello }hi this athat afsd\" adsfasdf}
```

Documentation : [regsub man page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/regsub.htm) & [regexp_how_to](http://www.tcl.tk/doc/howto/regexp81.tml)

Comment: My point is not that, I am able to get the result string, only that it is not in the form I expected. \" should not change dto \}, I want to skip the escaped "

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: This gives the correct output. Thanks for providing one workaround. But my main forucs is in understanding whats wrong with (?!re) type syntax to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

If you would reconsider using `regsub`, this transformation is simpler with the `string map` command:

```
string map {\\\" \\\" \" \}} $st
```

The gist of it is "replace `\"` with `\"` (i.e. keep it unchanged) but replace `"` with `}`". It looks awkward since (in this case) every character needs to be escaped, so `\"` becomes `\\\"` and so on, but it's really very straightforward.

Documentation: [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)